# can you no longer assign require to a variable and reference the variable

Tags: lua

im using lua5.1 and im a little confused on how require works
i've seen code have require assigned to a variable and use that

```lua
config = require("config") --outputs a Boolean value
--what I've seen in code
config = require("config")
local cfg = config.getConfig("some_config.conf")
```

Comment: If a module does not return a value, then `require` returns `true`.  If a module returns some value (usually a table), then `require` returns that table.  See your `config.lua` whether it contains a `return` statement at the end of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> --outputs a Boolean value

That is largely incorrect. `require` returns the return value of the Lua module that it loaded. If that module doesn't return a value, then it returns `true`. If the module couldn't be loaded, then it returns `false` followed by an error message.

Lua modules are *expected* to return a table containing the stuff inside that module. That is how the module idiom is expected to work, and most modules do so. As such, the `local varname = require "modulename"` idiom is typically how modules are accessed.

The older Lua idiom for modules (used mostly in Lua 5.0, through the `module` function) had modules just dump all of their functions into the global table, or a subtable within the global table. This has largely been abandoned for obvious reasons. Modules are now expected to respect the global table and leave it alone.

And please note the use of `local` here. You shouldn't dirty up the global table either.